# Do I need to repair this hole in the bottom flange of my I-joist?

Tags: construction, flange

The electrician made a hole in the bottom flange of the I-joist. Do you think any repair is necessary? The hole is diagonal from bottom to upper part of the flange and is about 3/4 inch. I read the specs that said do not cut or drill thru but it happened and made me anxious!

[image: flange drill]

Comment: What is the span of the I-Joist? What is the spacing of the joists? Is this joist the first in the row of joists? How far from the bearing end is the hole? Is the joist 2 span or 3 span? Is it a floor joist? Is there any other loads on the joist other than a uniform live load?

Comment: So it is 18 f span, 2 spans, 16 inch between joists, the hole is about 4 f from the end/stairs. And is floor joist about the sixth from side

Answer (score 1):

Yes some repair is probably needed, contact the supplier for guidance.

Comment: Which "supplier"?

Comment: whoever supplied the joist

Comment: There will likely be a manufacturer's name printed on the joists. Since this is a manufactured product, the manufacturer is the proper source for repair guidance. Adding some detail to the answer to support it would help turn what may be "technically" correct answers into actually useful ones.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you’ll probably need repair or replacement of I-Joist.  You answered some of my questions, but not all. I’ll make some assumptions and you can tell me if I’m correct.

Normally joists have compression in the top and tension in the bottom. Occasionally when an I-joist is in a 2 span situation, the compression and tension will reverse at or near the bearing point.

I doubt this applies in this situation because, 1) at 4’ the hole is too far from the bearing point for the reversal stresses to apply, 2) at 18’ span the joist is at or near its stress capacity, 3) if no other loads on the joist, (like a post) it could still require additional bracing.

I’d contact the truss manufacturer and give them the size, spacing, loading, span, etc. and see what the exact stress is in the bottom chord at that exact location. They can tell you if you need 50% or 25% of the chord.